# How to write unit test cases using dreamweaver cs5

Tags: php, phpunit, dreamweaver

I have a question of how to use dreamweaver to create unit tests for php. I know how to create in netbeans which has excellent plugin for the code coverage as well. I am wondering if dreamweaver has same functionalities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamweaver out of the box does not have any framework or extension for unit tests.

[Searching](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?searchfield=unit+test&search_exchange=3&search_category=-1&search_license=&search_rating=&search_platform=0&search_pubdate=&num=25&startnum=1&event=search&sticky=true&sort=0&rnav_dummy_tmpfield=&Submit=) on the Adobe Exchange yielded no results.

Comment: Well, then I believe netbeans and eclipse are far superior IDE compared to dreamweaver

Comment: Dreamweaver is really geared for designers.